# Java replaceAll() & split() irregularities

Tags: java, regex, string

I know, I know, now I have two problems 'n all that, but regex here means I don't have to write two complicated loops. Instead, I have a regex that only I understand, and I'll be employed for yonks.

I have a string, say `stack.overflow.questions[0].answer[1].postDate`, and I need to get the [0] and the [1], preferably in an array. "Easy!" my neurons exclaimed, just use regex and the `split` method on your input string; so I came up with this:

```
String[] tokens = input.split("[^\\[\\d\\]]");
```

which produced the following:

```
[, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , [0], , , , , , , [1]]
```

Oh dear. So, I thought, "what would `replaceAll` do in this instance?":

```
String onlyArrayIndexes = input.replaceAll("[^\\[\\d\\]]", "");
```

which produced:

```
[0][1]
```

Hmm. Why so? I'm looking for a two-element string array that contains "[0]" as the first element and "[1]" as the second. Why does split not work here, when the Javadocs declare they both use the Pattern class as per the [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)?

To summarise, I have two questions: **why does the `split()` call produce that large array with seemingly random space characters** and **am I right in thinking the replaceAll works because the regex replaces all characters not matching "[", a number and "]"**? What am I missing that means I expect them to produce similar output (OK that's three, and please don't answer "a clue?" to this one!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well from what I can see the `split` does work, it gives you an array that holds the string split for each match that is not a set of brackets with a digit in the middle.

as for the `replaceAll` I think your assumption is right. it removes everything (replace the match with `""`) that is not what you want.

From the [API documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

> Splits this string around matches of
>   the given regular expression.
>
> This method works as if by invoking
>   the two-argument split method with the
>   given expression and a limit argument
>   of zero. Trailing empty strings are
>   therefore not included in the
>   resulting array.
>
> The string "boo:and:foo", for example,
>   yields the following results with
>   these expressions:
>
> ```
> Regex     Result
> :     { "boo", "and", "foo" }
> o     { "b", "", ":and:f" }
> ```

Comment: Thank you, it was the fact that split gives me an element in the array for each match of my regex; this is what I was failing to understand!

Answer (score 2):

This is not a direct answer to your question, however I want to show you a great API that will suit your need.

Check out [Splitter](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) from Google Guava.

So for your example, you would use it like this:

```
Iterable<String> tokens = Splitter.onPattern("[^\\[\\d\\]]").omitEmptyStrings().trimResults().split(input);

//Now you get back an Iterable which you can iterate over. Much better than an Array.
for(String s : tokens) {
   System.out.println(s);
}
```

This prints:

`0`
`1`

Comment: A great suggestion, thanks. Right now I only have use for regex in this particular instance, but I'll go to Guava should I need it further.

Answer (score 2):

[`split`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) splits on *boundaries* defined by the regex you provide, so it's no great surprise you're getting lots of entries — nearly all of the characters in the string match your regex and so, by definition, are boundaries on which a split should occur.

[`replaceAll`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) *replaces* matches for your regex with the replacement you give it, which in your case is a blank string.

If you're trying to grab the `0` and the `1`, it's a trivial loop:

```
String text = "stack.overflow.questions[0].answer[1].postDate";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\[(\\d+)\\]");
Matcher m = pat.matcher(text);
List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
while (m.find()) {
    results.add(m.group(1)); // Or just .group() if you want the [] as well
}
String[] tokens = results.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Or if it's **always** exactly two of them:

```
String text = "stack.overflow.questions[0].answer[1].postDate";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(".*\\[(\\d+)\\].*\\[(\\d+)\\].*");
Matcher m = pat.matcher(text);
m.find();
String[] tokens = new String[2];
tokens[0] = m.group(1);
tokens[1] = m.group(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `split` is the wrong operation here.

In ruby, I'd tell you to `string.scan(/\[\d+\]/)`, which would give you the array `["[0]","[1]"]`

Java doesn't have a single-method equivalent, but we can write a `scan` method as follows:

```
public List<String> scan(String string, String regex){
   List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
   while(matcher.find()) {
      list.add(matcher.group());
   }
   return retval;
}
```

and we can call it as `scan(string,"\\[\\d+\\]")`

The equivalent Scala code is:

```
"""\[\d+\]""".r findAllIn string
```